# are there any alternatives to AppDomainSetup and CreateInstanceAndUnwrap for net-Standard2.0

Tags: c#, appdomain, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0, appdomainsetup

Im trying to make my code compile in netStandard2.0 and cant get over this. AppDomain is supported but has limmited methods. And AppDomainSetup is not supported. i have the following code that right now is Net Framework 4.7.1 compatible. is there any alternative to make it compile on NetStandard2.0??

```
AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
setup.ApplicationBase = m_ApplicationBase;
setup.PrivateBinPath = m_PrivateBinPath;

setup.ApplicationName = "TemplateCompiler " + m_AppDomainCount;
setup.LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.SingleDomain;
m_AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TemplateCompiler Appdomain " + 
m_AppDomainCount, null, setup);
m_AppDomain.AssemblyResolve += AppDomainAssemblyResolve;

m_RemoteLoader = (RemoteLoader) m_AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap 
(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(RemoteLoader).FullName);
```

Comment: why target .net standard? target the framework that has it.

Comment: @Camifonta No AFAIK. You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/) and [here](https://apisof.net/) which API exist in which target\version and also what planning for future versions.

Comment: @DanielA.White its part of a porject we are tryng to migrate to net standard2.0 as part of a request of our superiors.